# sort by count in another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 sql tables

1.Categories table

```
-id
-name
-url
-content
```

2.Entry table

```
-id
-title
-content
-cat //category
-view
-author
```

I want to sort all categories by the total number of categories in the entry table

I would like to sort the categories according to the values returned from this query:

```
  SELECT count(cat) as catcount, 
         cat 
    FROM entry 
GROUP BY cat 
ORDER BY catcount DESC
```

this query is currently returning two results. 20 places in the area I want to print. I would like to have random fields written in empty fields

```
  sample data: 
kitap
acil

expected data:
kitap
acil
random category.name 18 piece
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: And please tag your DBMS

Comment: the sample / expected result is really not clear. Which table are these items in? What data is in the other table? And why should the result show "category.name" 18 times, based on that? The sample needs to be complete, and the expected result needs to be directly based on the sample. Or...is what you have called "sample" data actually the current result of your query? It's not clear. "Sample data" in this context means the raw data in your tables. "expected result" means what you want your query to output. "current result" means what your query outputs right now.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want a `left join`?

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(e.id) as catcount
FROM category c LEFT JOIN
     entry e
     ON c.id = e.cat
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY catcount DESC ;
```

Comment: I want exp: kitap, acil, (random.cat.name), (random.cat.name), (...)

Answer (score 0):

More optimal way would be to group in subquery and then join on dictionary:

```
select c.cat_id, c.cat_name, e.cnt
from Categories as c
left join (
 select e.cat_id, count(*) as cnt
 from Entries as e
 group by e.cat_id
) as e
on e.cat_id = c.id
order by e.cnt desc
```

Comment: Please define random category name. For the random part you would also need to specify RDBMS you are using as it is very different for every DB. If you need number - no problem, otherwise you can generate random integer in range of category IDs and join by this in cases when there are no values. For totally random names you can generate few letters.